# Writing a contact to NFC tag on Android

Tags: android, nfc

Is there any tutorial or example that explains how I can make my android program write a specific contact (name and phone number) to NFC tag. So when the user touches the tag with his phone, it saves the contact to his phone contacts?

Comment: You can save name and phone number on NFC tag using application called 'NFC Tools' and read the card contain using below link:  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-nfc-tags-with-android--mobile-17278 link

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Using the VCARD type.

Inside your NFC event intent handler, use this method to build your NdefRecord:

```
public NdefRecord createVcardRecord(String name, String org, String tel, String email) 
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    String payloadStr = "BEGIN:VCARD" +"\n"+ 
                        "VERSION:2.1" +"\n" + 
                        "N:;" + name + "\n" + 
                        "ORG:"+org+"\n"+ 
                        "TEL:"+tel+"\n"+
                        "EMAIL:"+email+"\n
                        "+"END:VCARD";
    byte[] uriField = payloadStr.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
    byte[] payload = new byte[uriField.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(uriField, 0, payload, 1, uriField.length);
    NdefRecord nfcRecord = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA, 
            "text/vcard".getBytes(), 
            new byte[0], 
            payload);

    return nfcRecord;
}
```

Then add the record to your records array:

```
NdefRecord[] records = new NdefRecord[1];
records[0] = createVcardRecord("Henry", "Henry's Company", "0412345678", "henry@domain.com");
```

Pass the records array into an NdefMessage and you are ready to write:

```
NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(records);
Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
writeToTag(message, tag); // your tag writing function
```

Comment: @DigitalPerson: Assuming this worked, can you please mark this question answered?